# Using SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium() for Master Page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

Please refer to the topic http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/SaveViewState.aspx. The topic demonstrates how you can save ViewState to a file system over server so as to make ViewState very small on roundtrips. The author had created a class BasePage by inheriting System.Web.UI.Page and all the pages are derived from this class.

The site I am developing uses a masterpage and all the pages are derived from this masterpage. When I try to override `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium()`, a compilation error is generated indicating that there is no such method to override within System.Web.UI.MasterPage.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. Actually the aspx page is derived from System.Web.UI.Page while the masterpage is derived from Control class. There the method SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium() is available within aspx page only not in master page. You have to override this method within each aspx page or create your own base class derived from Page class and then override the method.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [PageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.aspx) override would be an easier way to change the ViewState persistance mechanism on all pages without requiring a base class.

Milan Negovan has written a good [blog post](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/page_state_persisters_overview.aspx) on the different options using the PageStatePersister, with some additional links.